# 5.1 -> 5.2 Laravel Breaking Change With Dingo API

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, dingo-api

I have a controller that is supposed to return an array of objects. It looks like this:

```
public function index($account)
{
    if(Auth::user()->accounts->contains($account))
    {
        $drones = $account->drones()->where('retired',false)->get()->sortBy('total_flight_time');
        $drones = $drones->reverse();
        return $drones;
    }
}
```

And I get the expected result of:

```
{ "drones": [ { "id": 21, ..... }, { "id": 26, ...... } ] }
```

However, upon upgrading to Laravel 5.2, without changing any of the code I now get the unexpected result of:

```
{ "drones": { "0": { "id": 21, .... }, "2": { "id": 26, ..... } } }
```

I've read the upgrade docs and don't see any changes to eloquent, I looked for issues in the docs and Github of Dingo and don't see anything that would cause this. What am I missing that's causing this huge breaking change?!

Thanks

Josh